# Is this possible make call from app, without asking user permission..?

Tags: javascript, nokia, nokia-s40

I'm developing Nokia S40 web app. I've implemented "Tel URI" scheme, like below shown, to make call for a given number from my app. and Its works perfectly..!

```
<a href="tel:+9196******72">Dial Me</a>
```

when i click the link to make the call, Its asking me permission checkpoint like

'Create call to +9196******72" 
        Yes / No.

now my question is, Can I make the call without this permission checkpoint...? Thanks in advance!!!